# iPhone 4 with Cordova (Phonegap) scales the view

Tags: iphone, cordova, retina-display

I have a strange problem.
I deployed a app designed for the iPhone 4 with Cordova.

But the Viewport is always double scaled, so webkit creates a 1280 * 1920 px view.

I have not idea why this is happening.
I already included

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;"/>
```

but it's still happening.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I finally found the solution, still it's pretty akward.

In cordova.plist I set `Enable viewport scale` to `yes`. But still in the meta viewport I had to do a `initial-scale=0.5`

Comment: No, I left it to `initial-scale=0.5` and finished the project with that workaround. Not sure what caused this bug.